# Parse nested JSON in Swift 4.1

Tags: json, swift, parsing, alamofire

I'm trying to parse a nested json in my application but I keep getting an error that I don't understand. With normal json it worked perfectly. Here's how I modeled the data:

```
import Foundation

struct Producer: Decodable {
    var data: ProducerData?
    var messages: [String]?
    var success: Int?

}

struct ProducerData : Decodable {
    let id: Int?
    let name: String?
    let login: String?
    let producer: EventProducer?
    let roles: [String]?
    let config: [String]?
}

struct EventProducer : Decodable {
    let id: Int?
    let name: String?
}
```

And here's the request and Decoding of the json:

```
Alamofire.request(url, headers: headers).responseJSON {
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print(response)
            do {
                response.result.value
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                jsonDecoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                self.producer = try jsonDecoder.decode(Producer.self, from: response.data!)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }

            break
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

The error I'm getting is:

> typeMismatch(Swift.Int, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Int but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: The error message is very clear: In the struct `ProducerData` (key path `data` > `id`)  you want to decode the key `id` as `Int` but it seems to be a `String`. Please learn to **read** the JSON: Everthing in double quotes is `String`, even `"12"` and `"false"`. And why is everything declared as optional?

Comment: Wow, thanks, it worked now! I'll be more careful with that. When I wrote these structs I didn't understand optionals very well, but I already changed that. Thanks again!

Comment: try to use `.responseData` instead